# Python inheritance, updating variable in parent class from child

Tags: python

How would I update `B.SET` with `A.SET` values while changing only class B?

```
class A(B):
    SET = {"var1": 1}

class B():
    SET = {"var2": 2}
```

Comment: I think you're mixing up instances and classes.

Comment: Hmm ... A can't inherit from B before B is defined ... Can you be a little more clear on what you want?

Comment: I wish to have `B.SET = {"var1": 1, "var2": 2}`

Comment: you can do `B.SET = {"var1": 1, "var2": 2}` already with the given code, so where is the problem?

Comment: This is an abstraction of a bigger problem, a developer has the option of defining `A.SET`, yet if he doesn't `B.SET` should be default. And various `__init__` definitions inside class A are not wanted. `B.SET` should be updated with `A.SET`.

Comment: @user2115494: Why the heck would you do that? What if another class `C` inherits from `B`? Should `C` see `A`'s alterations to `B`'s `SET`?

Comment: Can you clarify some things? Is `A` supposed to inherit from `B`, or vice versa (as it's written in the question, you'll get a `NameError` about `B` not being defined yet)? Are the `SET` attributes supposed to be `set` instances, rather than dictionaries? Do you want attribute variables, rather than class variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class T(object):
    SET = {}

A = T()
A.SET = {"var1": 1}

B = T()
B.SET = {"var1": 1, "var2": 2}
```

If this is not what you wanted, please explain more :-)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but I want to have all the changes to SET variable inside class B. Sorry, should have been clearer about that...

Answer (score 0):

I just renamed the `B.SET` to `B._SET` and updated inside `B.__init__`

```
class B():
    B._SET = {"var2": 1}
    def __init__(self):
        self._SET.update(self.SET)
```